# React onChange event for select tag not working on IE

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, internet-explorer

I have a dropdown in a React app that needs to work on IE11. I shouldn't use a submit button based on the design. I'm trying to trigger the submit event with `onChange` but it doesn't work on IE. The code that I'm using is working on other browsers:

```
<form method="POST" action={//...} ref={formRef}>
  <select
    name="//..."
    defaultValue={//...}
    onChange={() => formRef?.current?.submit()}
  >
      {available.map(item => (
        <option key={item.code} value={item.code}>
          {item.name}
        </option>
      ))}
  </select>
</form>
```

When I add a submit button like this the form action takes place on IE:

```
<form method="POST" action={//...} ref={formRef}>
...
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Also I tried this and it works on IE:

```
<form method="POST" action={//...} ref={formRef}>
...
  <button onClick={() => formRef?.current?.submit()}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

But I need to trigger it without the button. I also tried adding an event listener in the `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  selectRef.current?.addEventListener('change', () => {
    formRef.current?.submit()
  }
  return selectRef.current?.removeEventListener('change')
, []}
```

But this solution doesn't work on IE11 neither.
Are there any other options that I haven't tried?

Comment: What version of React are you using? Current versions [don't support IE at all](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#browser-support): *"**Note:** We do not support older browsers that don’t support ES5 methods or microtasks such as Internet Explorer. You may find that your apps do work in older browsers if polyfills such as [es5-shim and es5-sham](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) are included in the page, but you’re on your own if you choose to take this path."*

Comment: (I ask not to do IE-shaming, but to point out that if you really need to support IE, you may need to use an obsolete version of React or not use React at all.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's just a deprecation page luckily! The React version is the latest. So ig I'll need to use a non-react page. Thanks for clarifying!